# Will curses by parents on their children when they are angry count in Islam. Are there any Ahadith mentioning this topic?

Tags: dua

I know many of us and people we know will have parents who are always angry for many reasons / in general and will , instead of remaining calm , take it out on their children. What does Islam say in regards to cursing your own children or making bad dua against them? I know they are parents , and highly regarded in Islam. But will Allah listen to these bad dua's / curses and allow them to come true? I ask because many of us will be good children - obeying, performing salah - I know nobody is perfect with deen or personal life - but what if you are a good child and try your best to please your parent, but your parent is just very angry and curses at ANYTHING that may happen - even when you dont curse and mindful of Allah SWT? Does making dua to Allah to not accept their bad curses work? Please give me your insight and knowledge on this.and also what the Quran mentions in regard to this. Any help is appreciated .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Islam given high respect and place to parents and harm and disobeying them have serious consequences in this life and hereafter.

If parents ask to do something against Allah's order and against Shariah obviously you shouldn't obey them but even then you have to deny to them politely and respectfully. And Allah knows all and best what is in your heart and what's going on.

Cursing from anyone including parents is about showing their concerns and grievances and it doesn't means Allah as He knows about everything will act what cursing person says but Allah (as He the most just) considers the whole situation, the actual act, your intention etc.